# Reading excel file in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, reactjs

I am trying and banging my head already while trying to read excel file in Reactjs.

I have tried multiple libraries out there like, [Sheetjs](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx) , [excel-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/excel-parser), [exceljs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs) and so on (like 8-9) libraries.

I am getting weird and different errors in every library.

For example i am using [excel-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/excel-parser) and getting following error

```
Module not found: 'child_process'
```

That is because it is a node module and won't work in browser.

Anyone know some good and easy library that can work with **reactjs in browser**?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I have successfully read excel file using **Sheetjs**'s npm version **xlsx**.

Here is code:

```
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';
//f = file
var name = f.name;
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = (evt) => { // evt = on_file_select event
    /* Parse data */
    const bstr = evt.target.result;
    const wb = XLSX.read(bstr, {type:'binary'});
    /* Get first worksheet */
    const wsname = wb.SheetNames[0];
    const ws = wb.Sheets[wsname];
    /* Convert array of arrays */
    const data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_csv(ws, {header:1});
    /* Update state */
    console.log("Data>>>"+data);
};
reader.readAsBinaryString(f);
```

Comment: but i have a doubt in this. how to restrict the brows file should be only .xlsx format. Other files should allow to upload

Comment: how are you getting the file? Do you have to use a require with excel-loader?

Comment: Here is the repo demo for react
https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/tree/12597dcf7b524dd888499ba83285f64969938978/demos/react

Comment: For me there is a problem that if there is empty cell there is no column key and value in data at all and I expect to be like { colName: null }

Answer (score 19):

Noman Ali! Thank you.
I used, this code

```
const handleUpload = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    var files = e.target.files, f = files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        var data = e.target.result;
        let readedData = XLSX.read(data, {type: 'binary'});
        const wsname = readedData.SheetNames[0];
        const ws = readedData.Sheets[wsname];

        /* Convert array to json*/
        const dataParse = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, {header:1});
        setFileUploaded(dataParse);
    };
    reader.readAsBinaryString(f)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

One of the simplest way found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GUFzw4jo_E4):
This approach works for reading .xlsx, .txt or other formats as well.

Snippet:

```
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';
...

<input
type="file"
onInput={(e) => this._handleFile(e)}
/>
...

private _handleFile = async (e: any) => {
    console.log('reading input file:');
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    const data = await file.arrayBuffer();
    const workbook = XLSX.read(data);
    const worksheet = workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]];
    const jsonData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, {
        header: 1,
        defval: "",
    });

    //console.log(e.target.files[0]);
    //console.log(workbook);
    console.log(jsonData);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I find xlsx to work pretty well.
[xlsx Package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx)

Comment: Could you please answer this then> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46911079/reading-excel-in-javascript-is-converting-long-numbers-to-exponential

Answer (score 2):

you can use exceljs for reactjs, for example

```
import React from 'react';
import Excel from 'exceljs';

const Index = () => {
    const handleChange = (e) => {
        const file = e.target.files[0];
        const wb = new Excel.Workbook();
        const reader = new FileReader();

        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        reader.onload = () => {
            const buffer = reader.result;
            wb.xlsx.load(buffer).then((workbook) => {
                console.log(workbook, 'workbook instance');
                workbook.eachSheet((sheet, id) => {
                    sheet.eachRow((row, rowIndex) => {
                        console.log(row.values, rowIndex);
                    });
                });
            });
        };
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <div>Upload Excel File</div>
            <input type='file' onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)} />
        </div>
    );
};

Index.propTypes = {};
Index.defaultProps = {};

export default Index;
```