# ReactJS - How to skip empty rows in excel while reading with xlsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, excel

I'm successfully reading my Excel file in React by following this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46909260/7344164) as.

```
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        var data = e.target.result;
        let readedData = XLSX.read(data, {type: 'binary'});
        const wsname = readedData.SheetNames[0];
        const ws = readedData.Sheets[wsname];

        /* Converts a worksheet object to an array of JSON objects*/ 
        const parsedData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, {header:1});
        console.log(parsedData);
    }
    reader.readAsBinaryString(fileName)
```

But having a simple problem, i.e., it's reading empty rows as well and causing empty entries in array.
Output of `console.log(parsedData);` in the above code is

[image]

I know a quick hack is to remove empty entries from the array but I want to know a better approach to avoid this problem even happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit** - It's "blankrows" and not "blankRows"

I did a search and came across a similar question on gitmemory [here](https://gitmemory.com/issue/SheetJS/js-xlsx/1078/494210668), which shows that there's a blankRows property you can set to false in order to skip blank rows, which would look like this with your implementation:

```
/* Converts a worksheet object to an array of JSON objects*/ 
const parsedData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, {
    header:1,
    blankrows: false
});
```