# How can i read csv file in react js

Tags: reactjs, excel, exceljs

I am using the ExcelJS library in my React project to read CSV files, but couldn't get success.
can someone please give me a working demo code to read CSV files from ExcelJS in the React project

react version: 18.0.2

i am expecting my excel sheet data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading excel file in Reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46909260/reading-excel-file-in-reactjs)

Comment: Try [`exceljs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs) as seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75360850/1762224).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.